# How to inject a raw L2 packet as an incoming packet to an interface on Linux?

Tags: linux, network-programming, packets

I need to inject some L2 packets(customized) to an specific interface as incoming packets in Linux to test some applications running on it.

Is there any libraries(python preferred)/examples that can help? I was skimming through the Scrapy library, but then it looks like it can only inject packets to the network as outgoing packets?

Comment: Do you want to inject packets only to a specific interface e.g `eth0` OR do you want to simulate packets coming into the linux stack generally?

Comment: to a specific interface, cause we have a slightly different stack than  the default eth->IP->tcp->user space stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the native linux `bridge` module available then you can use it in this way. Create a bridge

```
brctl addbr <brname>
```

Now create a virtual `eth` pair (default names `veth0`, `veth1`). veths are connected L2 devices

```
ip link add type veth
ifconfig veth0 up
ifconfig veth1 <some_ip> up
```

Now add your specific interface, lets say `eth0`, and one side of the `veth` pair to this bridge.

```
brctl addif <brname> eth0
brctl addif <brname> veth0
```

This adds both these interfaces to the bridge. Now when you send traffic on `veth0`, you should be able to get it on `eth0` also(based on normal L2 switch functionality). To send traffic on `veth0` you simply need to  pump traffic into `veth1` since both of them are connected internally. So lets say you want to use `tcpreplay`, just do

```
tcpreply -i veth1 yourpcap.pcap
```

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Thanks, I am accepting this approach since this should be the right way to do it in a general setup. In our case, we don't have this bridge module available. I ended up writing a tap device driver.